# Find all possible increasing subsequences of a given length in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the efficient way to find all possible increasing sub-sequences of a given length in Scala?

For eg: Suppose there is a sequence of numbers as follows:

```
7 6 9 11 16 10 12
```

The possible increasing subsequences of size 3 for the above sequence are :

```
7 9 11
7 9 16
7 9 10
7 9 12
7 11 16
7 11 12
7 10 12
6 9 11
6 9 16 
etc…
```

I would like to know which Scala data structures would help in finding the sub-sequences quickly.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? You've tagged this question with 5 of them...Also: is there a constraint on the length of the sub-sequence? I see you create sub-sequences of 3 elements only...

Comment: you can improve this question by providing some code that you have tried and removing tags other than scala

Comment: Since you mention Scala in the title and the question body, I've removed the other, irrelevant language tags.  Don't tag a question with multiple languages — you will be mercilessly downvoted.

Comment: I am using Scala but then would appreciate if someone gives the optimised approach irrespective of language used. Subsequence length can be anything, I have just given the example

Comment: You need to show that you have made some attempt to answer this before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Scala solution to your question:

```
def subSequence[A](list: List[A], size: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): List[List[A]] =
  if (size <= 1) {
    list.map(List(_))
  } else {
    ( for {
        t1 <- list.tails if t1.length >= size - 1
        a = t1.head
        t2 <- subSequence(t1.tail, size - 1)
        b = t2.head if ord.lt(a, b)
      } yield a :: t2
    ).toList
  }
```

Hopefully someone else will provide a tail-recursive version of this which should perform better.

Answer (score -1):

This is one possible solution.

```
val l = List(7, 6, 9, 11, 16, 10, 12)
l.combinations(3).filter(x => x == x.sorted) // this gives the desired result for size 3 and `3` can be changed to some number `n` for different size of combinations.
```

I just created combinations and filtered later which might not be very efficient.But, I am interested to know more efficient answers by generating only increasing combinations.

Comment: This works with the test data but will break if there are duplicate values in the list because `combinations` removes duplicates and `sorted` does not enforce increasing values.